# How to calculate the sum of a property

Tags: python, django

Hello everyone here is my question:

**models.py**

```
class Plant(models.Model)
   nominal_power = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   module_nominal_power= models.PositiveIntegerField()

@property
    def no_modules(self):
       return round(self.nominal_power*1000/self.module_nominal_power)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    plants = Plant.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    total_power = plants.aggregate(sum=Sum('nominal_power'))
    total_no_modules = plants.aggregate(sum=Sum('no_modules'))['sum']
    template = 'data/home.html'
    context = {'plants':plants,
               'total_power':total_power,
               'total_no_modules':total_no_modules}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

And I get the error Cannot resolve keyword 'no_modules' into field.**Cannot resolve keyword 'no_modules' into field.**

I undestand the meaning of the failure but how can I get the total number?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use F class

```
from django.db.models import F
total_no_modules = plants.aggregate(sum=Sum(F('nominal_power')*1000-F('module_nominal_power')))
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but I want to replace `(F('nominal_power')*1000-F('module_nominal_power')`  with `no_modules`.

Comment: You can't use model property in your queries, because django orm don't can translate your property function to SQL queries. But if you want use no modules, you can get all plants and sum property, like this: sum(map(lambda plant: plant.no_module, plants))

Answer (score 0):

@Marcin you are correct but I was looking for this:

```
def home(request):
        plants = Plant.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        total_power = plants.aggregate(sum=Sum('nominal_power'))
        total_no_modules = 0
        for plant in plants
            total_no_modules = total_no_modules + plant.no_modules
        template = 'data/home.html'
        context = {'plants':plants,
                   'total_power':total_power,
                   'total_no_modules':total_no_modules}
        return render(request, template, context)
```